# Strange Java performance issue (JIT optimization?)

Tags: java, performance

I'm experiencing very strange performance degradation in my utility class - shortly I'm adding method `last(revIndex)` into my clone of native [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) class, which does not have access by index.

```
public E last(int revIndex) {
    return (E)elements[arrBackPos(revIndex)];
}

protected int arrBackPos(int index) {
    int size = (tail - head) & (elements.length - 1);
    if( index > 0 || -index >= size )
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("...");
    return (tail + index - 1) & (elements.length - 1);
}
```

While testing my code with NetBeans' profiler it showed that `arrBackPos` is the far-behind-others CPU consumer. After removing safety-check (1st three lines) - code became much quicker (10 sec vs. 20 sec), but ... after trying to optimize the code I noticed that in some conditions that same safety-check-code adds negligible time (something like 10.2 sec vs. 10 sec) - just removing/re-adding/recompiling the code may fix the problem, for some time, but for some unknown reason re-appears at later executions.

So ... what it is? Why same code in same execution condition may run 2 times slower? Is there any way to make performance consistently fast?

*I would suspect that JIT is not triggered on short runs, but same problem appears on the data-sets running for 1..2 minutes.*

Comment: Just to be sure this is JIT related, try running with the `-Xcomp` flag. This option forces JIT of everything. If your performance is *still* unstable, you might need to consider something else...

Comment: How do you measure performance? Please, show the benchmark. Incorrect benchmarks are most often the reason of strange performance effects.

Comment: @apangin, I do not have a benchmark in the classic 'meaning' of it - i'm just executing real-life code over the predefined dataset, @Paulo Mattos, I'll try `-Xcomp` next time problem re-occurs - i just do not have clear way to reproduce it.